# cf dev start fails - failed to reach Pivotal Network

Tags: cloud-foundry

I just started to use pcf.
Today i have installed pcf dev v0.17 as well as virtual box 5.1 in Red Hat 6.5.
Unfortunately I can't start the cf dev.
I receive the following error:

```
[root@dpavqlxrh6-02 ~]# cf dev start
Please retrieve your Pivotal Network API from:
https://network.pivotal.io/users/dashboard/edit-profile

API token>
FAILED
Error: failed to reach Pivotal Network: Post https://dtb5pzswcit1e.cloudfront.net/product_files/pcfdev/pcfdev-v0.136.0.ova?Expires=1468505522&Signature=bqxaC76GvYNLN7HvrEVrlz%!E(MISSING)53brSM6tlnSi%!E(MISSING)JhoTESIg3cIOWm5YMldT8BY-%!E(MISSING)G7ofWbbS22pUOrdqvucCE1074iyiMaNRqiyGAg5U%!E(MISSING)%!E(MISSING)C5BxXJzEjZnB1hvwsXPWyBvpNRdl6SMnG4PGhnaJPBRF0gypfJIm7qaX9nbjWob4Awng_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLAM6FL65BYZP7UQ&filename=pcfdev-v0.136.0.ova: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

Any help would be great! :)

Answer (score 0):

Before getting into a PCF DEV installation , you just try to create a free account on Pivotal cloud Foundry that will give you the API Token.